# Angular-Meteor update to 1.6.1.1 typescript compiler missing declarations

Tags: angular, typescript, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm upgrading my project from v1.6.0.1 to v1.6.1.1. In previous version, there is declaration.d.ts file with all global variables. After update, it seems declarations.d.ts file not working.

I think it's related typescript compilers of angular2-compilers and angular-compilers?

Answer (score 1):

Add at the beginning of the top file, eg server/main.ts:

`/// <reference path="<declaration-file-path>/<declaration-file-name>.d.ts" />`

Work with Meteor 1.6.1 and angular-compilers .

See [typescript compiler ignoring *.d.ts files #1909](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/1909#issuecomment-391506659)

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly the issue? Is it with an npm package?

Can you provide your package.json and .meteor/packages files?

Since Meteor 1.6.1, you can't use angular2-compilers anymore, only angular-compilers.

Comment: There is no need to post package.json nor .meteor/packages. I'm just asking why typescript compiler of angular-compiler not reading declarations.d.ts file? How can I declare global variables in new angular-compiler?